# Import data from BigQuery to Cloud Storage in different project

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-python-api

**I have two projects under the same account:**

- **projectA** with BQ and **projectB** with cloud storage
- **projectA** has BQ with dataset and table - ***testDataset.testTable***
- **prjectB** has cloud storage and bucket - ***testBucket***
- I use python, google cloud rest api
- account key credentials for every project, with different permissions: **projectA** key has permissions only for BQ; **projectB** has permissions only for cloud storage

**What I need:**

import data from **projectA** testDataset.testTable to **projectB** testBucket

**Problems**

- of course, I'm running into error **Permission denied** while I'm trying to do it, because apparently, **projectA** key does not have permissions for **projectB** storage and etc
- another strange issue as I have *testBucket* in **projetB** I can't create a bucket with the same name in **projectA** and getting

> This bucket name is already in use. Bucket names must be globally
>   unique. Try another name.

So, looks like all accounts are connected I guess it means should be possible to import data from one account to another one via API

**What can I do in this case?**

Answer (score 0):

You put this wrong. You need to provide access to the user account on both projects to have accessible across projects. So there needs to be a user authorized to do the BQ thing and also the GCP thing on the different project.

Also `Bucket names must be globally unique` it means I can't create the name as well, it's global (for the entire planet you reserved that name, not just for project)